# Erlang dead letter queue

Tags: erlang

Let's say my Erlang application receives an important message from the outside (through an exposed API endpoint, for example). Due to a bug in the application or an incorrectly formatted message the process handling the message crashes.

What happens to the message? How can I influence what happens to the message? And what happens to the other messages waiting in the process mailbox? Do I have to introduce a hierarchy of processes just to make sure that no messages are lost?

Is there something like Akka's dead letter queue in Erlang? Let's say I want to handle the message later - either by fixing the message or fixing the bug in the application itself, and then rerunning the message processing.

I am surprised how little information about this topic is available.

Comment: Every language has its own paradigm to some extent, and you work within it, or against it. It's good to have the high performance low guarantee facilities for when you want them, and if you want more, in Erlangs case OTP will probably provide most of what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no information because there is no dead letter queue, if  you application crashed while processing your message the message would be already received, why would it go on a dead letter queue (if one existed).

Such a queue would be a major scalability issue with not much use (you would get arbitrary messages which couldn't be sent and would be totally out of context)

If you need to make sure a message is processed you usually use a way to get a reply back when the message is processed like a gen_server call.

And if your messages are such important that it would be a catastrophe if lost you should probably persist it in a external DB, because otherwise if your computer crashes what would happen to all the messages in transit?

Comment: This implies that for the use case mentioned in the question an Erlang application could and should be combined with an external messaging system (such as RabbitMQ).

Comment: @GaborKulcsar Not necessarily. It depends on the architecture/concept underlying the overall system (encompassing the client, intermediates, and server). Usually the service that does the processing isn't the one that determines how important it is -- that is either an intermediary or client's concern. RabbitMQ may be such an intermediary, but it is *way* overboard to say "it could and should be combined" in every case a message may me important. Most often a client-side retry of a serialized or idempotent message is sufficient.

Comment: It's a bit like UDP vs TCP; TCP is considered reliable and UDP isn't, but if UDP is sufficient then it will be a much more efficient tool. Horses for courses.

Comment: @GaborKulcsar It is worth noting that RabbitMQ is written in Erlang. :-)